# Finding the function from a definite integral?

Tags: calculus

If I had an integral, as shown below,
$$\dfrac{\int_{0}^{1} a(x) \cdot x^{2} \; dx}{\int_{0}^{1} a(x)\; dx}=\dfrac{1}{2}$$
How would I figure out the function $a(x)$, is there way or do I have to make a guess and test it?

Comment: *The function* is simply not fixed. This is more or less like asking *given $f(1)=2019$, what is $f(x)$?*

Comment: Every non-zero constant function will do, also $a(x) = x$ from polynomials

Comment: @Jakobian $a(x)=c$ will give $\frac{\frac c3}{c}=\frac13$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many choices. At some point you're going to have to make a choice arbitrarily, or use information from the deeper context of the question (things you haven't told us about) to choose.

We can see $a(x) = 1$ (or any constant) won't work. The average value of $x^2$ for $x \in [0,1]$ is only $\frac13.$ We need to "weight the average" to count the larger values of $x^2$ more heavily so that the "average" comes out to $\frac12$ instead.
The function $a(x)$ is the "weight".

One possible approach is to assume $a(x) = x^k$ for some real number $k$. Work out the ratio of the integrals, which will be some expression in $k$.
You want that expression to equal $\frac12.$ Assume it does, and solve for $k.$

There are many other possibilities, for example if you don't mind an integrand with finitely many jump discontinuities then $a(x) = \lfloor x + k\rfloor$ could do the job.

Comment: I did assume $x^{k}$ and after solving, managed to get a value for $k$, which is $k=1$, therefore $a(x)=x$. That was very helpful, thank you so much!

Comment: The solution $a(x) = x$ was also given away in a comment under the question. But it seems more satisfying to derive it from a method that doesn't assume you have guessed the exact answer immediately.

Comment: a(x) can be x but as pointed out, there are lots of other possibilities too.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is the function $a(x)=0$ for all $x$ but there might be others.

Comment: But then we divide by $0$

Comment: You can rewrite the formula by bringing the denominator on the right site. Then there are no issues with dividing by 0 and the solution is the same.

Comment: $\frac00$ is indeterminate. You can make $\frac00=1$ and $\frac00=2$ by "moving the denominator to the other side", but $1\ne2$.

Comment: I know. But the equation in question is $\int \dots = \frac{1}{2}\int \dots$ which can be solved without any problems.